# Ubuntu Resolving Host & Wifi Problem

Tags: networking, internet, 17.04, dns

I have a problem with my WiFi connection, When I am trying to connect to my own WiFi at home everything is fine. if i am connecting to another network and trying to surf (Chrome) I have a note of Resolving host.. and an error of DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET and there is no ping to 8.8.8.8 by example.

When I tried route -n I have got:
169.254.0.0
I read a recommend to uninstall avahi-autoipd and now I don't see the zeroconf.

I tried to add name servers to resolv.conf (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4),
reconfiguration resolvconf: dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf,
uncomment dns=masq
etc..

I upgrade my ubuntu from 16.04 to 17.04, But the problem of DNS still as is.

Please try to help me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1:
Checking Default route
Use one of these commands:

```
route -n
```

or

```
ip r
```

Ask a new IP address and amend the connection with the next command:

```
dhclient -v wlan0
```

Now, all should work fine!