# A lot of drivers are not working all of a sudden

Tags: drivers

OS VERSION - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.
KERNEL VERSION- 5.8.0-38-generic.
I am new to Linux. Everything was working fine until all of a sudden when I turned my pc on and a lot of drivers are not working. For example the wifi option has disappeared, trackpad is not working while the external mouse is, keyboard functions are not workin whereas the keyborad is working. I cannot find the option in the settings to control the brightness of my screen and backlight of keyboard.

I have also observed that even animations are not working along with these. Sorry for my ignorance as I am new to this platform

Comment: Please start with your OS & release details.  Most changes are the result of modifications (additional software, removed packages) made in the prior session, and/or updates that occurred prior session.  If it was a kernel upgrade; you can boot into the older kernel at grub to return to the prior condition & confirm it's a kernel issue; but to start with, your OS & release details are key.

Comment: Add details like What OS, version and what version of the kernel you are running on. Also, have you upgraded the kernel? Edit the question and add these details. Open the terminal and `uname --r` to know the version of Kernel you are running on.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: I am not even able to connect to the internet as I am not able to connect through ethernet cable

Comment: This sounds like you have trouble with the 5.8 kernel. Try to reboot to the latest 5.4 kernel and see if that works better.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306565/how-are-ubuntu-supplied-drivers-verified-for-production-lts-updates/1306569#1306569 But we need some more information.